# Should I reach out to my interviewer after unexpectedly not receiving a reply

Tags: interviewing

I went to an interview 5 weeks ago and was interviewed by a manager in the company (large, international company, +5000). I was told to be patient by the interviewer as they had many applicants. After two weeks I reached out to merely **inform** of my travel plans (as per [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/74852/i-forgot-to-mention-my-travel-plans-during-the-interview-is-it-appropriate-to-c/74873#74873) question) and that I am available when abroad on phone/email. I received a reply, saying that they *expect* to give me a reply the following week.

Two weeks have passed without any reply. Should I reach out to the manager or will it make me seem desperate/unprofessional? On the other hand, I don't want to miss a potential job because I am labelled "not-proactive".

Answer (score 3):

Just reach out. It is your interest and you have waited for an extra week, if the news are going to be bad, there's nothing you can do about it but at least you will know.

Answer (score 3):

If they like someone, then they wouldn't want to lose the potential hire due to their negligence. You should proactively reach out to them and enquire about the progress. Wait for an extra 2/3 days after passage of time specified by them.

There is absolutely nothing wrong in asking information. If you want something, then you've got to ask.